# Where can I find MySQL Path/URL for NetBeans?

Tags: mysql, sql, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I'm trying to do school JAVA EE project and I have to connect schema made in mysql from MYSql.

part of code is (for SQL select) :

```
String dbURL = "";
String user = "root";
String password = "root";
```

[and i apperently have no URL somehow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQoPE.jpg)

Any ideas on that? I'm new to SQL and JAVA EE so i face lots of problems :/

Comment: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html

Comment: In your screenshot : localhost:3306

Comment: when i type there jdbc::mysql://localhost:3306/mysql
i get "The specified admin tool path is not a vaild file or URL".

Comment: i got sql connector also but it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need a running mysql instance. There are 2 possibilities :

(1) You need the domain :

- local instance / `domain : localhost`
- Remote instance / `domain or IP`

(2) You need the port of the mysql server instance

- Default is `3306`

(3) The name of the database you want to connect to.

- Lets say you need to connect to the database `test`

Now in order to connect to the database you will need to generate the connection url. In our case since (I assume) you want to write java, the url is in `jdbc` format

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
```

In order to connect netbeans to a mysql Database you will need to follow the next steps :

1. Locate the service tab on the project tab and right click on the **Databases**.
   [image]
2. Select the Mysql Driver and click next. (If the driver misses just download the file from the suggested portal it will be a jar).
   [image]
   [image]
3. Finally fill the appropriate information on the next frame
   [image]

If you need parameters to your jdbc URL you can do so like :

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?param1=value1
```

You can find more detailed information on the Netbeans website : https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html